# Reattaching Drain Rod to Trip Lever

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

The trip lever on my bathtub drain has broken.  The small loop on the back of the trip lever drain broke off (see picture) and thus can't connect to the rod anymore.  Now when I went to purchase a new trip lever I found that the connecting loop on the new trip lever was too small to fit into the end of the curved rod (see picture).  Also, my existing trip lever is a Gerber.

Here are my questions:

1. Do I need a specific kind of trip lever to fit that rod?
2. If the loop on the trip lever is of a standard size, then how do I connect the loop of the rod to the loop on the back of a new trip lever?

I'd also like to not have to buy a new rod mechanism, but rather just replace the trip lever if possible.

Thanks for your time!

[image: Front of Trip Lever]

[image: Broken Trip Lever]

[image: Rod and Lever]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design,the Gerber brand *bucket and wire* assembly uses a direct connection between the upper wire and the hole in the trip lever, by simply feeding the wire loop through the hole.

[image]

Other brands commonly use a threaded yoke (for height adjustment) and cotter pin at that connection.

You will need to find a Gerber brand trip plate and lever ([they are out there](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gerber-Trip-Linkage-KGR97-171/204353982)) or one designed for Gerber, or fix up a creative work-around with the one you bought.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Thanks for the detailed explanation and diagram...very helpful.  Now since I don't need the whole assembly do you think I could just purchase something like this [Gerber face plate assembly](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Gerber-G0097130-Face-Plate-Assembly-for-Trip-Lever-Drains-97-130?gclid=Cj0KCQjwrJ7nBRD5ARIsAATMxss37p4vfsFoY71euv8-Vej3gZKXaQgRPnBkLBm4bVzsFxj1JaLmNYcaAtccEALw_wcB)?

Comment: Absolutely, you can even tell by the pics in your link that there is a larger hole in the lever to accommodate the wire connection.

Comment: Well, I ordered it from the link above (best price I could find) and I installed it quite painlessly today.  I forgot to order screws with it, but the old ones I had were fine.  I also had to bend the metal loop out a bit with a pair of pliers to get it through the hole, and then bend it back to close the loop after it was connected.  It's working great!  Thanks again for your detailed answer.